# Replacing form by sliding it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple login system.

I have a form **inside** a small box that has a couple of Text Fields and a Button. When the button *Log In* is pressed, I want the form to slide to the right, and a new form to come out of the left side of my previously mentioned box.

I managed to create something similar to this effect, but it I don't think this is the best way to do it.

I made an example of what Im doing here:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m09jkh9w/)

This is the code for changing the forms:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loginDiv').hide();
        $('#loginB').click(function() {
            $('#signupDiv').fadeOut(400).animate({
                'margin-left': '30vw'
                }, {duration: '500', queue: false, complete: function() {
                        $('#loginDiv').fadeIn(400).animate({
                            'margin-left': '0vw'
                            }, {duration: '500', queue: false, complete: function() {;

                        }});
            }});
        });
    });
```

How can I make this better?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the two forms in position absolute and animate their left position with JQuery. Like this example:

HTML

```
<div id="divContainer">
  <div id="divSignup">
    div Signup
  </div>
  <div id="divLogin">
    div Login
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#divContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#divSignup,
#divLogin {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
}

#divSignup {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
}

#divLogin {
  background-color: red;
  left: 500px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('#divSignup').click( function() { 

    $('#divSignup').animate( 

    { "left": "-500px"},
  { duration: 500, 
    step: function(nowLeft) {

                var curLeft = nowLeft + 500;

                $('#divLogin').css('left', curLeft);

    }
  }
)

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fabio1983/x5e3xzqf/